# How to get and describe the a pod in a one-liner?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Using `kubectl`, I want to `describe` one of the pods (can be a random one) filtered on a labelSelector. Currently, I perform it in two steps:

1. `get` the pods,
2. Copy the name of one of the results, and `describe` it.

```bash
$ kubectl get pods -l app=my-app,environment=production
$ kubectl describe pods my-pod-name-copied-from-the-results
```

Can I do that with a one-liner, and without copying the pod name every single time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one liner to get the first pod's decribe (if scaled to more than 1):

```
kubectl -n namespace describe po "$(kubectl -n namespace get po -l app.kubernetes.io/name=my-app --no-headers -o name|cut -d/ -f2|head -1)"
```

If you need a random one (as mentioned in the other answer's comments):

```
kubectl -n namespace describe po "$(kubectl -n namespace get po -l app.kubernetes.io/name=my-app --no-headers -o name|cut -d/ -f2|shuf -n1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could try something like this:

**Note:** This works for a single pod only!

```bash
kubectl describe pods $(basename $(kubectl get pods -l job-name=curl-job -o name --no-headers))
```

Explanation:

```bash
kubectl get pods -l job-name=curl-job -o name --no-headers
```

Returns the name of a pod with a given label, for example:

`pod/curl-job-p5rsb`

But if you use just this, you'll get:

```
error: there is no need to specify a resource type as a separate argument when passing arguments in resource/name form
```

So, we use `basename` to get rid of the `pod/` part:

Running:

```bash
basename $(kubectl get pods -l job-name=curl-job -o name --no-headers)
```

Returns:

```
curl-job-p5rsb
```

Now, you can pass this as an argument to `kubectl describe pods`

This completes the entire command.

```bash
kubectl describe pods \
   $(basename $(kubectl get pods -l job-name=curl-job -o name --no-headers))
```

---

EDIT:

If you want to get the top pod out of many pods, use `head -n 1`, like this:

```bash
kubectl describe pods $(basename $(kubectl get pods -l stage=test8 -o name --no-headers | head -n 1))
```

Comment: Thanks, but for my case, I have multiple results returning from the `kubectl get pods -l job-name=curl-job -o name --no-headers=true` command and I want to get a random (or top one) from the list.

Comment: `--no-headers=true` can be just `--no-headers`, as long as the parameter is specified it counts as `true`